# List extraction from a list of list

Tags: python

Currently, i have a list of list containing:

```
lst = [['abc','def'],['efg','hjk']]
```

and i want to extract each element in the list into it's own individual list together with an added index at the front, to produce an output of:

```
lst = [[1,'abc'],[1,'def'],[2,'efg'],[2,'hjk']]
```

I tried a way where:

```
for ind,val in enumerate(lst):
    print(ind+1,val)
```

but I'm getting:

```
1 ['abc','def']
2 ['efg','hjk']
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in a list comprehension like this:

```
new_lst = [[idx, val] for idx, i in enumerate(lst,1) for val in i]

# [[1, 'abc'], [1, 'def'], [2, 'efg'], [2, 'hjk']]
```

Or, if you prefer the syntax of the nested loop:

```
new_list = []

for idx, i in enumerate(lst,1):
    for val in i:
        new_list.append([idx,val])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = [['abc','def'],['efg','hjk']]
new_list =[]

lenght_list = len(lst)
counter = 0

while counter < lenght_list:
    for elem in lst[counter]:
        new_list.append([counter+1, elem]) #counter starts from 0
    counter +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Only a slight modification needed. I understand correctly you want to have a list afterwards?

```
lst2 = []
for ind,val in enumerate(lst):
    for element in val:
        lst2.append([ind+1, element])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and straightforward.

```
first = [['abc','def'],['efg','hjk']]
new_first = []
for i,v in enumerate(first):
    second = v
    for j,w in enumerate(second):
        new_first.append(((i+1), w))

print(new_first)
```

Produces:

```
[(1, 'abc'), (1, 'def'), (2, 'efg'), (2, 'hjk')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with range :

```
lst = [['abc','def'],['efg','hjk']]

print([[i+1,sub_item] for i in range(len(lst)) for sub_item in lst[i]])
```

output:

```
[[1, 'abc'], [1, 'def'], [2, 'efg'], [2, 'hjk']]
```